# VoiceOver navigation doesn't work on tab panels if wrapper has aria-label

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, voiceover, wai-aria

I recently noticed a very weird problem with VoiceOver's web navigation on tabs and tab panels. In particular, if the wrapper wrapping the tabs and tab panels has attribute aria-label set, then VoiceOver navigation cannot navigate to tab panel when switching tabs.

The problem may be hard to describe by words, thus I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNz6a/1/) to demonstrate. Notice that the outside wrapper div has `aria-label="Wrapper"`. Below are the steps to recreate the problem:

1. Run the jsFiddle to get the result area loaded.
2. Navigate to one of the tab buttons either by using mouse or keyboard navigation.
3. Activate VoiceOver.
4. Use `VO + Right Arrow` to try to navigate to tab panel content, this should work.
5. Use `VO + Left Arrow` to navigate back to the second tab, press `VO + Space` to activate the tab.
6. Now using `VO + Right Arrow` try to navigate to the new tab panel. **This will fail.**

After the above steps, switching between tabs doesn not fix the problem, you cannot navigate to the panel whatsoever. **But if you remove the `aria-label="Wrapper"` from the wrapper div, everything works again.**

Does anyone familiar with VoiceOver and WAI-ARIA know where the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried this with voiceover on when you launch Safari? I have no problems with your sample on iOS using Voiceover or Windows with Firefox using Jaws 15 as the screen reader so this looks to be OSX specific. You can try emailing accessibility@apple.com to report a bug.

Comment: @Jared thanks for commenting, I tried with other browsers (Chrome, Safari, FF) and strangely, FF 26.0 didn't have a problem with it. I'm not sure whether I should blame VoiceOver, the browsers, or myself...

Comment: Just discovered this myself. Did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: @Phil It was awhile ago so I couldn't remember what exactly I did. However, I'm fairly certain that I concluded this to be a OSX VoiceOver specific issue and couldn't get around it. This may be something to do with how VoiceOver handles dynamic content being injected into the page, so I would suggest looking at how to show/hide contents without removing them altogether (like using `display: none`).

Comment: Thanks. I looked more into it, and can't seem to find anything other than it being a bug. I've filed a bug report with Apple. I'll let you know where that goes (probably nowhere).

Answer (score 1):

If the two tabs contain just the strings "Tab panel 1" and "tab panel 2", then the issue appears to be fixed. Tested with OS X 10.11.1.

Yes, I know that the question is pretty old, but I'm adding my answer for future reference, just in case! :-)